# Use the same bind-Value for two properties

Tags: c#, blazor

Hi I have a question that looks simple but I don't have an answer to it.
I have a model like this:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    [Display(Name ="Firstname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="surname")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    //Ohter attributes
}
```

And I need to add `FullName` like this:

```cs
[Display(Name = "FullName")]
public string FullName=> $"{FirstName } {LastName}";
```

So I can use it in inputText like this:

```html
<InputText id="FullName" @bind-Value="Employee.FullName" />
```

but I can't do that because I need a setter otherwise I will get an error.

Thanks for help

Comment: You can use `FullName` one-way binding to display the information.
To edit you need the property setter, how would the application know which part of the inputed text is `FirstName` and `LastName`?
Better approach is to use individual inputs, or if you really want to make it work like that you could take the `TextChangedEvent` and read/split the `string` however you want and then set values to `FirstName` and `LastName`

Comment: `FullName` is a readonly property - `=> ....` is shorthand for a getter,  so of course you can't set it.  Why are you trying to attach an edit control to a read only property???  If you want a setter, then declare one and do a bit of text manipulation with say RegEx to split out the first and last names.  Different cultures, different formats, so probably fraught with errors.  Far better to have two inputs.

Comment: Thanks, @LeandroRequena Could you please add your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FullName` one-way binding to display the information. To edit you need the property setter, how would the application know which part of the inputed text is `FirstName` and `LastName`? Better approach is to use individual inputs, or if you really want to make it work like that you could take the `TextChangedEvent` and read/split the string however you want and then set values to `FirstName` and `LastName`.